# how too have Automatic horizontal scrolling of layout in android after few seconds

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scroll

I have a listview which contains some textview and imageview. i have a horizontal scroll of this layout.
Below this layout i have another layout which is static for all the items of listview. so now I want the listview items to scroll horizontally after few seconds. how can i achieve this.??

Comment: use a thread, make a while loop, every while loop animate the scroll and sleep for some time

Comment: can u elobrate the "animate the scroll"

Comment: If you are using a scrollview : ScrollView.scrollTo() else you should look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread are the only answer. You can use modified versions of thread named timer,Handler etc....